# Varchar2 datatype allows systimestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, varchar2, systimestamp

I have one table with varchar2 datatypes like below

```
create table t11 (aa varchar2(100),bb varchar2(100));
```

Now, if I trying to insert `systimestamp` into above, values are getting inserted:

```
insert into t11 values (systimestamp,systimestamp);
commit;
```

Question is why this conversion is allowed in Oracle.

I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your column type is `varchar2` and the return type of `systimestamp` is `timestamp`. `timestamp` can not be stored directly into `varchar2` column, Oracle implicitly convert the `timestamp` value into `varchar2` with the rule specified in the init parameter, `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`.

You can read [Data Conversion Rules](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements002.htm#i55214) and [NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams132.htm#REFRN10131) for more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle have Implicit Data Conversion [Read more about here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements002.htm#SQLRF00214) that depends on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`

> Implicit conversion depends on the context in which it occurs and may
>   not work the same way in every case. For example, implicit conversion
>   from a datetime value to a VARCHAR2 value may return an unexpected
>   year depending on the value of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter